# twisted logging with django

Tags: django, twisted

My server is out in production, and I am running django on top of twisted. 
I have the following for logging:

```
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
...
reactor.listenTCP(DJANGO_PORT, server.Site(wsgi_root, logPath=os.path.join('./log', '.django.log')))
```

However, I am only seeing these in my .django.log.X files:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2010:16:48:22 +0000] "GET /statics/css/xxx.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1110 "http://www.xxx.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"
```

I know for a fact that registration is throwing a lot of errors, but then the log has NOTHING about the exceptions and errors being thrown!

How can I actually output errors generated by the WSGI file?

Note: I think it has something to do with the fact that I have to change log.startLogging(sys.stdout). However, if the solution indeed is to change that, I would like to know how I can output to BOTH sys.stdout as well the file.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't use Twisted's logging APIs.  `twisted.python.log.startLogging` only configures Twisted's logging system.  Django probably uses the stdlib `logging` module.  So you'll have to configure that in order to get Django log output written somewhere useful.  You see the request logs in your .django.log.X files because those are logged by the Twisted HTTP server, independently of whatever Django logs.